# How to add a button per row in google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, spreadsheet, google-apps

I have a simple spreadsheet with multiple rows I want to add button to each of it automatically.

On click this button will remove the entire row and move it to another spreadsheet.

I've looked online and couldn't find a way to add buttons to spreadsheets. Some people suggest to insert drawings and assign macros, but looks like the latest version lacks this feature.

I've also read about google app sript. I was able to add buttons to a menu, but not directly to each row of a spreadsheet.

Do you have any advice or suggestion on how to better achieve this?

Comment: My sugestion is to use one column as a condition for a menu script to copy it to another spreadsheet.

Comment: @Jacobvdb, thanks for the suggestion. If I do this, how can I capture cell edit event?

Comment: Well you don't, in stead you first mark all the rows in a certain column with a particular condition and than with a script which you activate through the menu you'll copy all the rows with that condition to another Spreadsheet. [manual for menus](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/defining_menus)

Comment: You cannot insert buttons in spreadsheet cells. Use a "marker" as suggested above and use that mark as a condition for a script called from a menu.

Comment: What about a hyperlink? would that be possible?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the you create a column(say 10) at the end of each row with a List Data Validation of "Move Row" and create an onEdit function like so

```
function onEdit(eventInfo) {
  if (eventInfo.range.getColumn() == 10 && eventInfo.value == "Move Row")
  {
    var ss = eventInfo.source;
    var row = eventInfo.range.getRow();
    var range = ss.getRange(row, 1, 10) // this is your range, do with it what you will
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So this script is not entirely my own work, but the results of something  I was working on with help.

It will look in a source sheet, look at a column you specify (by number), and look for a value in this sheet.

If matched, it will move that row to another sheet, within the spreadshet, of your choosing.

```
    function moveRowInternalSheet()
{

  var sourceSheet = ""; 
  var columnNumberToWatch = ;
  var valueToFind = "";
  var destinationSheet = "";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheet);

  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var counter = 1; //starts looking in second row, due to header
  var archive = [];



  while (counter < values.length)
  {


    if (values[counter][columnNumberToWatch - 1] == valueToFind)
    {


      archive.push(values.splice(counter, 1)[0]); 
    }
    else
    {
    // If the value to find is not found. Then increment the counter by 1

      counter++;
    }
  }





  var archiveLength = archive.length;




  if (!archiveLength) return; 



  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(destinationSheet);


  var lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();



  var requiredRows = lastRow + archiveLength - targetSheet.getMaxRows();



  if (requiredRows > 0) targetSheet.insertRowsAfter(lastRow, requiredRows);



  targetSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, archiveLength, archive[0].length).setValues(archive);


  sheet.clearContents();


  sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```